# How to new article with blogger api by php?

Tags: php, blogger

How to new article with blogger api by php with title, content and keyword?

I would like coding simple  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Blogger API](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/1_docs/) is deprecated, use [GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/). Documentation [contains examples](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#CreatingPublicEntries) in php.

You need just to send xml in [special format](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingPublicEntries).

Comment: can make without Zend ? it big framework

Comment: Look at the last link in my answer. You need to send xml in this format to blogger.